# How can I see the every each line one by one?

Tags: java, jtextarea

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How I append text to textarea with using swingworker class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11982395/how-i-append-text-to-textarea-with-using-swingworker-class)

I append my jtextarea many lines in for loop. When i add lines , I dont see any line on text but when the for loop finish all of them is showing up. How can I see the every each line one by one ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't execute your process in the [Event Dispatching Thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html), it blocks the repaint updates from occurring.

You should make use of the [SwingWorker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html) API

Also, take a look at

- [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/)

Let me guess what you're doing

```
while (doSomeWork) {
   // do some processing
   textArea.append(someText);
}
```

Or possibly a `for` loop

And you're, some how expecting the UI to magically be updated?

Unfourtantly, as much as I would love it to work like that, it doesn't work that way.

In order for the screen to be updated, you must allow the Event Dispatching Thread to continue running, so it can handle repaint requests (& a bunch of other important things), you need to off load your processing to another thread.

No, there isn't any other way to it, & the easiest way is to use the SwingWorker

Comment: I dont understand. give some example here ? is it easier way ?

Comment: Have a read through some of the links. If you have a particular question, either search SO or post a new question

Comment: pls give some code sample pls. I want to add lines in loop like you write up.

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11927167/jtextarea-appending-problems/11927201#11927201 I left lots of examples

Comment: I  dont want it, it s about moving file. just i want append text

Comment: Read the answer, it's appending text to the end of JTextArea.  The concept is exactly the same. You can't expect us to help you if you don't help yourself ;)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but use this in your for loop:
jTextArea.updateUI();

Comment: it doesnot work I try it

Comment: try jframe.updateUI(); or jpanel.updateUI(); too.

Comment: @markhmaltion updateUI has nothing to do with repainting, it has to do with the Look & Feel, while he's blocking the EDT, nothing will get repaintng