# Search a folder structure for files based on metadata

Tags: java, image, search

I want to write a functionality in Java which performs search through a folder structure(folder containing sub folders) for files(most probably image files) based on metadata of the files. Could anyone please tell me which Java API  has such a feature. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "metadata"?

Comment: "metadata" - I meant file attributes like owner, date of creation, date of modification, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Start by taking a look at [Managing Metadata (File and File Store Attributes)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/fileAttr.html) and [Walking the File Tree](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/walk.html)

For example, take a look at [Swingworker with FileVisitor class and walkFileTree(), which iterates internally over a "set" of files in a directory tree; where to publish()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20060366/swingworker-with-filevisitor-class-and-walkfiletree-which-iterates-internally/20060689#20060689)