# How to export a log file on button click?

Tags: java, swing, file, file-io

I have my application log file stored in the project directory. For better UI experience I want to put a button in my java application which says "Export Log files".  I want to read from an existing file on a disk and allow it to be saved by user anywhere he wants so he won't have to go searching for the log files.

How is it possible to do it? I tried to Google but the result of these keyword searches doesn't show the links I would be interested in.

Comment: learn basics of Java first.  Learn how to make a Swing UI with a button, learn how to display file dialog in Swing UI, learn how to read and write file.

Comment: Which part are you stuck on? [How to Use Buttons, Check Boxes, and Radio Buttons](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html)? [How to Write an Action Listeners](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html)? Or [Basic I/O](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/)?

Comment: @MadProgrammer i am stuck on the File I/O part . How to ``copy`` & ``paste`` file from one location to the new user specified location . Will i need to read file A and then write to file B or I can avoid read and writing .

Comment: *"I tried to google but the result of these keyword searches"*  Really?  I suspect your searches were far too specific.  Try instead searching 'x java tutorial' where `x` is a single word dealing with part of the task.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Ok thanks I shall be more specific . I shall go through the File I/O parts .

Comment: Amen, if you Google for "X then Y then Z", you'll never find it. Better Google for X, then for Y, then for Z, and then synthesize the whole from the parts using your intellect and efforts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start by taking a look at [Basic I/O](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/).  This will provide you with the basic concept of dealing with input/output streams and readers and writers.

You can also have a look at [File I/O (Featuring NIO.2)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/fileio.html) which provides actually examples of copying files and directories...

Now, personally, I prefer to manually copy files using `Input/OutputStream`s or `Reader`/`Writers`.  The reasons for this is I can provide progress indication of the copy process, which the NIO.2 API's don't provide...

For example, see [JTextArea appending problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11927167/jtextarea-appending-problems/11927201#11927201)

Comment: Good 'Swing' things to go with that might be `SwingWorker` and `ProgressMonitorInputStream`.  Especially handy for those drives that power down to save trees (or something).

Comment: @AndrewThompson Yep, was hunting for an example :D

Comment: Nice example.  But since I already upvoted it, guess I'll just add an upvote to the comment.  :)

Comment: @MadProgrammer i get it now . I shall be able to handle it from here :-) Thanks for the help !